# Cancel a program in MATLAB

Tags: user-interface, matlab, save

I have this code:

```
fileName = inputdlg('Please enter the name for your figures');
directoryName = uigetdir('','Please select a folder to save to');
if directoryName == 0      %# User pressed the "Cancel" button...
directoryName = '';      %#   ...so choose the empty string for the folder
end
filePath = fullfile(directoryName,fileName{1});  %# Create the file path
extensions = {'fig','bmp'};
for k = 1:length(extensions)
  saveas(gcf,filePath,extensions{k});  %# Save the file
  set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto');
end
```

It has some problem. When I run it, this error occurs:

> ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in ==> fyp_editor>uipushtool9_ClickedCallback at 1607
>      filePath = fullfile(directoryName,fileName{1});  %# Create the file path.

And another thing is when i pressed the cancel button, it kkeep going to filepath. How I want to do something like; when I push Cancel, then it will cancel the save program.

Answer (score 1):

If the user presses Cancel fileName will be empty ( 0x0 cell array). fileName{1} is what causes the exception

Comment: Run "fileName = inputdlg('Please enter the name for your figures')" and see what happens to fileName when you press Cancel in the dialog window.